# c# If I pass a parameter in SqlCommand, like operator in sqlcommand doesn't work

Tags: c#, sqlcommand

Here's the query that I need to perform:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Faq WHERE IdApplicazione = @IdApp AND (TestoDomanda LIKE '%search%' OR TestoRisposta LIKE '%@search%')
```

I'm trying to perform it in C# by using SqlCommand. So what I do is this:

```cs
query = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Faq WHERE IdApp = @IdApp " +
    "AND (TestoDomanda LIKE @search OR TestoRisposta LIKE @search) ");

query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", dataApp);
string variable = "test";

SqlParameter search = new SqlParameter("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255)
{
    Value = "'%" + variable + "%'"
};

query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", search);

SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString(DB_NEWS, USERID_DBNEWS, PASS_DBNEWS, INITIALCATALOG_DBNEWS));
sqlConnection.Open();

query.Connection = sqlConnection;
int count = 0;
try
{
    using SqlDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        count = reader.GetInt32(0);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString())
}
```

So, debugging, when is on the instruction   if (reader.Read())  it goes to the exception.. I assume that there's no record returned by the query.

I've also tried to:

```cs
query = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Faq WHERE IdApp = @IdApp " +
    "AND (TestoDomanda LIKE '%@search%' OR TestoRisposta LIKE '%@search'% ) ");
```

But still the same, `reader.read()` goes in exception.

If I change @search with the value '%test%' :

```cs
query = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Faq WHERE IdApp = @IdApp " +
    "AND (TestoDomanda LIKE '%test%' OR TestoRisposta LIKE '%test'% ) ");
query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", dataApp);
```

It works. So I assume it's a problem with '%%' operator, because I've tried with @idApp only and it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "it goes to the exception" What exception, you've not added the exception details to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing a string as a parameter, you omit the single quotes; the value is the content itself. So:

```
Value = "%" + variable + "%"
```

(the quotes are only for *literal* values in text SQL, so it knows where the value starts and ends)

You also just add the parameter:

```
query.Parameters.Add(search);
```

(by using `AddWithValue` you're adding a second parameter called `@search` whose value is the first parameter object)